# Why do odd dimensions and even dimensions behave differently?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

It is well known that odd and even dimensions work differently.

- [Waves propagation in odd dimensions is unlike propagation in even dimensions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/intuitive-explanation-of-the-difference-between-waves-in-odd-and-even-dimensions)
- [A parity operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28physics%29#Effect_of_spatial_inversion_on_some_variables_of_classical_physics) is a rotation in even dimensions, but cannot be represented as a rotation in odd dimensions.
- [Even dimensional spheres do not admit continuous nonvanishing vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), but odd dimensional spheres do.

Is there some unifying reason for these differences? Why is dimensional parity so important?

(If you know of any more interesting differences, please leave a comment and I will add them to the list.)

Comment: Some of these items (e.g., non-vanishing fields on the sphere) can be explained by noting that an even-dimensional real vector space may be viewed as a complex vector space.

Comment: You may enjoy some of the answers here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5372/dimension-leaps

Answer (score 30):

For *real* vector spaces, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^N$, one important difference between odd and even $N$ is that every real polynomial with *odd* order has a real zero, while there are real polynomials with *even* order that only have complex zeros.

Thus, a real invertible $N\times N$ matrix *always* has a non-zero eigenvector if $N$ is odd (because the characteristic polynomial has order $N$, and by the above has a zero). For even $N$, however, there are invertible real matrices with no non-zero eigenvector.

This means that in even-dimensional spaces, there are invertible linear mappings without an invariant one-dimensional subspace, while in odd-dimensional spaces, invertible linear mappings always have a one-dimensional invariant subspace. If you look only at rotations, you get that rotations in an odd-dimensional space always keep at least a line fixed, while in an even-dimensional space they do not.

That's a pretty huge geometric difference between odd- and even-dimensional spaces, that should explain a least some of the items in the question.

Answer (score 19):

This feels more like a big-list/community-wiki question rather than
a bounty problem...  Here are two examples:

i) An even-dimensional space supports symplectic forms;
an odd-dimensional one does not.  [**Symplectic** = *bilinear,
alternating, and nondegenerate*; *bilinear* means it corresponds
to some $n\times n$ matrix $A$, and then *alternating* means
$A$ is skew-symmetric and *nondegenerate* means $\det A \neq 0$.
For skew-symmetric $A$ we have 
$\det A = \det (-A^*) = (-1)^n \det(A^*) = (-1)^n \det A$,
so for $n$ odd the determinant must vanish; while for even $n$
it's easy to construct nondegenerate examples, such as the block matrix
$({\phantom-0 \; I \atop -I \; 0})$ where $I$ is the identity matrix
of order $n/2$.]

ii) The Euler characteristic of a sphere of dimension $n$ is
$1 + (-1)^n$ which is zero **iff** $n$ is odd.  So you can
[comb
an even-dimensional coconut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#Higher_dimensions) (whose surface is an odd-dimensional sphere)
but not an odd-dimensional one.  [To comb the unit ball in ${\bf R}^{2m}$,
identify ${\bf R}^{2m}$ with ${\bf C}^m$, and associate to each unit vector $v$
the tangent vector in the direction $iv$, which is orthogonal to $v$.]

[**Added later:** *(i) and (ii) are related because the block matrix
$({\phantom-0 \; I \atop -I \; 0})$ is rotation by $i$.  But I see that
the OP already mentioned the "hairy ball theorem" and linked to the same 
Wikipedia page.  So I offer a third example*.]

iii) The real orthogonal groups of even and odd order behave differently
as Lie groups: $SO_{2m+1}$ (for $m \geq 1$) is simple of type $B_m$, 
while $SO_{2m}$ ($m \geq 2$) has nontrivial center $\{\pm 1\}$ 
and its quotient by the center is simple once $m > 2$ and of type $D_m$.

Answer (score 0):

Another example, where odd and even dimensions behave differently: the complexity of a convex polytope spanned by $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is of magnitude $O(n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor})$. Moreover, this bound best-possible as witnessed by the cyclic polytope. For more information, see the below Wikipedia links or Chapter 5.5 in Matoušek's book "Lectures on Discrete Geometry"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Finite_point_sets
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_bound_theorem