# Representation theoretic explanation of Huygens' Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetry, wave-equation

**Huygens' principle** -- Wave equations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ seem similar for different $n$, but behave quite differently depending on the parity of $n$: waves in odd dimensional spaces never look back, while waves in even dimensional spaces linger. A more vivid depiction can be found in this related [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/intuitive-explanation-of-the-difference-between-waves-in-odd-and-even-dimensions)

> .. when you switch a light bulb on and then off (in 3D), there will be a light wave traveling with the speed on light and behind the wave, there will be total darkness. But when you throw a rock into a pond (with a 2D surface), there will be lots of waves traveling outwards from where the rock hit the water and, in theory, the water will never a still again.

There are several ways to explain the difference. One is by looking at the solutions to the PDE directly, one uses [complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8803/562467), one interprets waves in a case as a "projection" of another case..

#### Question

In this post, I'm looking for a representation theoretic explanation. Indeed, the wave equations look pretty similar for all $n$, and indeed all properties of waves are *entailed in the equations. The only (hopeful) difference I notice is the symmetries that involve: the representation theory of $\frak{so}(n,1)$ is quite different based on the parity of* $n$! There's already a hint in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/609763/562467) without details. I hope someone would point out a more detailed account that show Huygens' principle alone this line. To me, this will be more satisfactory as an intuitive explanation.

Comment: In odd spatial dimensions the fundamental solution of the wave operator is supported on the light-cone, while in even spatial dimensions its support is the solid cone. This _can_ be explained in terms of intertwinings among principal series repns of the relevant orthogonal groups, yes, if one wants...?

Comment: @paulgarrett if one wants...?

Comment: The complex analysis involved in meromorphic continuation of intertwining operators given by integrals is very similar to meromorphic continuation of corresponding homogeneous distributions/functions... So I myself would just talk about distributions with homogeneity/invariance conditions, rather than characterizing them as "spherical vectors" in principal series. I think the latter possible viewpoint does not gain much in this case.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are looking for but Huygens' principle is closely related to [contact manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry#Some_historical_remarks).

Comment: See also Howe & Tan's book "Non-Abelian Harmonic Analysis - Applications Of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$", Chapter IV.4.

Comment: @AlpUzman: Thanks a lot. Very interesting reference.